# Website where I can browse domain names

Tags: domains

I was wondering if there is a website where I can browse trough available domain names.

I often create new websites and getting a good name is always a pain. Because when I settle for a good name the domain is almost always taken.

While browsing trough them you can get some inspiration, and see if they are free also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try http://nameboy.com

Comment: Cool, nice one to add to the list. I already found a good name I could use. The best part of it is that it gives you the availability of all the TLD's, and its not that complicated to use. I am going to take this one as the answer although it does not differ much from the others answers.

Answer (score 1):

The website http://bustaname.com is supposed to help you choose a domain name based on keywords you give it. However, you should double check that the names are actually available, since I have heard of cases of the site incorrectly showing a name as available when it really isn't.

Comment: Nice one. This one has a lot of options. Defanately one I could use.

Answer (score 1):

I love [domainr](http://domai.nr/) for its instant lookup, like Google Suggest.

Comment: Good tool for doing lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any registrar worth their salt will suggest similar domain name whenever you do a domain search on their website. They usually append things like "online" or append "e" to them but they also do recommend decent names on occasion as well. That's the closet thing I've seen to what you are looking for. (Not including domain auctions but those technically aren't freely available).

Answer (score 0):

I've found this site:

```
http://www.namestation.com/
```

Helpful in generating domain names, and it checks if they are available too.

Comment: When using two keyword it treats them "strange"

Comment: It does give some strange outcomes once in a while. Only downside is that you cannot see the availability of different TLD's at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As John stated most domain sellers have such tools, I use http://www.godaddy.com/ and find it satisfying. You can also try some sites for expired(expiring) domains like http://www.registercompass.com/.

Good luck with the search.

Answer (score 0):

My registrar of choice, [DirectNIC](http://www.directnic.com/), has a similar search option which will make generally meaningful suggestions regarding available domains based on searches other people have run in the past, expired domains, etc.  They will also suggest taken names that are available for sale if you have some coin to spend.

Comment: Yes this is not really what I was looking for. It does give good suggestions, but you need some inspiration to begin with. And the prices are pretty high also.

Answer (score 0):

The website http://instantdomainsearch.com searches common prefixes (.com, .net, and .org) after each character you type. However there are some instances where it reports false positives (i.e. it shows a site as available, when it actually isn't).

Answer (score 0):

The DMOZ is an open directory project for websites, also a recommended way to add your website to in order for search engines to find those new sites, who may not have links to them yet.
This is exactly what you are looking for.

Ofc. it is not complete, as no other dictionary will be.
But it should give you, categorized by theme etc, a good list of domain names and thus ideas.

Answer (score 0):

http://whois.net let's you search by keywords, or you can use their WHOIS lookup, which will suggest similar domains for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information regarding domain from here

http://domain.indiatimes.com/WebSol/shopping/domainHome.sh